# Swift: Extend Optional Array

Tags: swift, generics, option-type

I'd like to extend `Optional`, where `Wrapped` is an array (with elements of any type). In other words, I want to add a function to `[Any]?`. I'm just not sure how to declare that. I've tried:

1.

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: Array
```

results in:

```
error: reference to generic type 'Array' requires arguments in <...>
```

2.

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: Array<Any>
```

results in:

```
type 'Wrapped' constrained to non-protocol type 'Array<Any>'
```

and various other similar declarations. Help is appreciated.

Comment: What would this extension be, exactly? In other words, what functionality would it be that you would wish to add only to `[Any]?`

Comment: I'd like to add a convenience function that 1) appends an element if the array is non-nil and 2) initializes the array with just the element if the array is nil.

Comment: @ConnorNeville You mean `array = (array ?? []) + [element]`? IMO that's not really worth an extension (considering the workarounds you'd have to go through in order to make it work).

Comment: Doh. That's a much more concise way of doing it than what I was repeatedly writing. I'll just do that, thanks.

Comment: @ConnorNeville No problem :) Although I do feel the need to question the use of an optional array, is it not possible for it just to be a non-optional empty array?

Answer (score 16):

I am kinda late, but maybe I can help.

In swift 4, you can do this

`extension Optional where Wrapped: Collection {`

If you need to access the Element type of the array you can do:

`Wrapped.Iterator.Element`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the Collection protocol, this is what I needed actually

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to the party but it still might help future readers. Using Wrapped `RangeReplaceableCollection` to support strings as well:

---

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    mutating func append(_ element: Wrapped.Element) {
        self = (self ?? .init()) + CollectionOfOne(element)
    }
    mutating func append<S: Sequence>(contentsOf sequence: S) where S.Element == Wrapped.Element {
        self = (self ?? .init()) + sequence
    }
}
```

---

```
var optionalString: String?
optionalString.append("a")
optionalString  //  "a"
optionalString.append(contentsOf: "bc")
optionalString  //  "abc"
optionalString.append(contentsOf: ["d", "e"])
optionalString  //  "abcde"
var optionalArray: [Int]?
optionalArray.append(1)
optionalArray  //  [1]
optionalArray.append(contentsOf: [2,3])
optionalArray  //  [2,3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes the problem here is that in this line,

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: Array<Any>
```

the 'Array' should be a protocol, in a more general way :

```
extension Type where Element: Protocol
```

The solution I got is ugly but works, consider this:

```
protocol ArrayOfAny {}
struct ArrayAny<Element: Any>: ArrayOfAny {
    let array: [Element]
    init(_ array: [Element]) {
        self.array = array
    }
}
```

Because this:

```
extension Array: ArrayOfAny where Element: Any {}
```

is not supported...

then you can just do this:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: ArrayOfAny
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

A better solution for this problem is using generic functions on `Optional` like this (here you are only adding functions to Optional if it really is an `Array`):

```swift
extension Optional {
    mutating func appendAndSetIfNil<E>(_ element: Wrapped.Element) where Wrapped == [E] {
        self = (self ?? []) + [element]
    }

    mutating func appendAndSetIfNil<S>(contentsOf newElements: S) where S: Sequence, Wrapped == [S.Element] {
        self = (self ?? []) + newElements
    }
}
```

This is just an example where the `append` function basically has been added conditionally to `Optional` if its `Wrapped` Type is an `Array`. In this case here the value is changed from `nil` to `[]` before appending.

But you can do anything here!

Be aware that this approach does not work in all circumstances, but in this one, it works!